# Why is UserDetailsService being used in filters? JWT

Tags: jwt

I checked a lot of tutorials and examples of jwt, for example, if you google "spring-security jwt example" you will probably see those links:

1. https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/
2. https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world
3. https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt

**Question)** Their authFilters use UserDetailsService, so they fetching data from Database as it just a Simple Token, and not JWT.

So I think I don't understand something.

**UPD:** what I would do:

Or create my custom Authentication and custom AuthProvider.

Or just use JwtUtil class which will decode jwt and then create default UsernamePasswordAuthToken and set it into SecurityContextHolder.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Do you suggest to use OAuth2? If you do, for now, I would like to just get into simple jwt implementation for better understanding it. Actually, I had a look at OAuth, but it is a bit complicated for me now(theoretically I got it, but not realization).

Comment: Somewhere you have to store the user data and that's why your links use the UserDetailService. My link uses a Authorization server that is a more common scenario

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Why do we need to store User data in that case if we are using JWT? It already has required data about user

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I see only one scenario for UserDetailsService in Security by JWT, it is post request "/login" and there we find a User by Username calling this UserDetailsService, then encode User to jwt and return it to the Client.

Comment: You can't trust the JWT token. So you have to check it in any way

Comment: @SimonMartinelli but https://jwt.io/introduction/ "This information can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed."

Comment: Oh yes sorry. I meant who is creating the JWT token in your case?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli In apps that I linked above, auth server and resource server it is the same server. But does it matter who created JWT, if we have a secret key?

Comment: No but the examples that you mentioned do both

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It seems I got it. because the client can easily check jwt header and payload. So the client can modify payload either. Right?

Comment: Yes everything that comes from client can be manipulated

Comment: No actually I was wrong, even if somebody will replace payload. The signature will be invalid cause it constructed by Header+Payload+Secret. So post still under question.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - it's a nice query, I am looking for an answer for the same, did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another review, I noticed, that I missed important note in [Rajeev Singh's tutorial on callicoder](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/#5-custom-spring-security-authenticationfilter)

> Note that, the database hit in the above filter is optional. You could
>   also encode the user’s username and roles inside JWT claims and create
>   the UserDetails object by parsing those claims from the JWT. That
>   would avoid the database hit.
>
> However, Loading the current details of the user from the database
>   might still be helpful. For example, you might wanna disallow login
>   with this JWT if the user’s role has changed, or the user has updated
>   his password after the creation of this JWT.